New vent covers too shallow to cover duct protrusion?
Just replaced all the baseboards in my house and attempting to replace the vent covers. My vents and returns have this metal lip that sticks out resulting in my new vent covers being too thin. Any solutions? Or am I forced to use the old ones? I really hope not cause the old ones are banged up and caked with paint and don’t open/close.
https://imgur.com/a/3TYxn7p



Typically, base trim is installed after vents so it fits to them. There are all manner of vent covers to be found. If you really want to use these you'll have to wrap the opening with something to fur it out.
Mitering your base trim up and over would've worked well. By making 90° turns to vertical, then over and down, you leave the base trim profile as a nice detail outside the vent cover. If you're willing to pull some of your completed work off and redo it that might be the most elegant option.
This photo shows the general idea, but your trim would be partially behind the vent, not around it.

source
Otherwise, find something to fill the gap and hide the galvanized metal. Thin vinyl plank could work, or more wood trim.

The thin metal could also be trimmed back a bit.

Not unless the base trim is going to be refit.

@crip659 it looks like one problem is that even trimming the duct, the register flange would be outside the baseboard.  The baseboard could be trimmed back to make room for the flange, but it may look odd.  I do think isherwood's mitering idea will probably look best.  That way the register flange will be flush all the way around (except obvs the bottom, where it doesn't need to be).
